# IndexOutOfRangeException - RichText

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, selection

I got a RichTextBox (txt) and an OpenFileDialog (Open1). When I try the following, I have a IndexOutOfRangeException on the specified line:

```
Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If (Open1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        fName = Open1.FileName
        txt.LoadFile(fName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < txt.Lines.Length
            AnalyseLine(i)
            i = i + 1
        End While
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AnalyseLine(ByVal line As Integer)
    Select Case txt.Lines(line).Substring(0, 1) '''' EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE ''''
        ' [...]
    End Select
End Sub
```

The exception throws everytime, no matter what the line variable worth.
And I really don't understand why, because it throws the same exception with every text file. Moreover, it seems like this issue appears only when a new file is open, because with the following code, it works fine...

```
Private Sub txt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt.TextChanged
    AnalyseLine(txt.GetLineFromCharIndex(txt.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine))
End Sub
```

Comment: I got it working, by replacing

    txt.LoadFile(fName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

by

    txt.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fName)

But I still don't understand...

Answer (score 2):

A line is probably just an empty string (last line I'm guessing), so check for it:

```
Private Sub AnalyseLine(ByVal line As Integer)
  If txt.Lines(line).Length > 0 Then
    Select Case txt.Lines(line).Substring(0, 1)
      ' [...]
    End Select
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nah it doesn't works, now it throws the exception on the If statement

Answer (score 0):

AnalyseLine has problems.
1) You shouldn't assume line is going to be valid and should be checked that it is in range of 0...  If it is used outside of the while look it can fail.
2) What if txt is null.  It will fail.
3) You do need to check length to see that the it is > 0
4) Why are you using substring instead of an array index [0]?  You are using a method to get only 1 character.  Bad coding.

Too many problems with the code.  It wouldn't pass a peer review.